# Full Page Background Slider not appearing correctly on Mobile Devices

Tags: wordpress, image, responsive-design

It would appear that the full-sized background image shows up correctly if placed in Landscape orientation on mobile devices but not in portrait mode. Is there a workaround for the portrait orientation on mobile devices?

Any sort of responses appreciated!!

Site: candasixfortune.com

Comment: please add code to your questions, instead of urls. You will get more views, answers (and votes) if you ask well-structured questions. Just a tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent element for the images has a position:fixed property and the images have a position:absolute property. The image is positioned relative to the page currently. You need to add a container to the images with a position:relative property.
This would be as follows:

```
<div id="bg-body">
<div style="position:relative">
<img src="">
</div>
</div>
```

Also remove the top:-50% applied to #bg-body, top:60px applied to #bg-body img, and set height to auto.